# Reuse or copy *sql.Rows in Golang

Tags: sql, database, pointers, go, copy

Is it possible to reuse the same `*sql.Rows` after the `*sql.Rows.Next()` was called so I could pass it to another function?

```
rows, err := db.Query(...)
for rows.Next() {
    // rows.Scan()
}
anotherFunction(rows) // NOT WORKING: This rows became empty.
```

I tried to make another copy of the `*sql.Rows` but it didn't work.

```
rows, err := db.Query(...)
anotherRows := *rows
// PANIC: call of load copies lock value: database/sql.Rows contains sync.RWMutex
```

Comment: When err is returned, rows will be nil, the dereference `*rows` make crash, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `database/sql` package does not provide any means to `rewind` the Rows, after you have read them, i.e. it is a "forward only" result set.

Moreover, it will maintain a link to the underlying (physical) database connection, inside it, making it a bad idea to copy it or pass it around.

If you need to apply multiple functions to your data, just `Scan` all the rows, to get a slice of data objects, and then pass this around.

Scan will make a copy of the data you read:

> Scan copies the columns from the matched row into the values pointed at by dest.

so you can then safely `Close` your `Rows` object (releasing any associated database resources).

You should watch out for errors too, after executing the Query (`err`) and after reading the rows, via `rows.Err()`.